# Нужна ли здесь запятая? "Я не говорил что это за человек"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая в предложении "Я не говорил что это за человек"?

И чем вообще выступает "что" в этом предложении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Я не говорил, **что** это за **человек**.*

1. Предложение сложноподчиненное (СПП) с придаточным изъяснительным, поэтому ставится запятая. Первая основа: *я не говорил*. Вторая основа: *что это за человек*.

Союзное слово (не союз!) ***ЧТО*** относится к фразеологическому сочетанию ***что за***, а предложение  нужно понимать так: *Я не говорил, ***какой*** это человек.*

2. О значении сочетания ***ЧТО ЗА***

***Что за*** (в вопросе, прямом или косвенном, или в восклицании) — какой? (какая? какое?). Димитрий я иль нет — что им за дело? Пушкин. Что у тебя за страсть кур красть? Что это за напасть такая? Гончаров. — Что у меня за характер!...
[https://kartaslov.ru/значение-слова/что+за](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE+%D0%B7%D0%B0)

3. **Со второй основой** надо разбираться отдельно: ***что это за человек*** (какой это человек).

Здесь *это* — подлежащее, *что за человек* (какой человек) — составное именное сказуемое. В именную часть входит неразложимое сочетание "что за человек".

Answer (score 0):

В предложении "Я не говорил, что это за человек", две грамматические основы: *"я — не говорил"* и *"это — что за человек"*.
Фраза "что за" определяет человека по аналогии с тождественной фразой "какой именно" и является союзным словом.

Comment: Грамматический разбор НЕКОРРЕКТНЫЙ. И двоеточие на ставят только для того, чтобы что-то чем-то казалось.

Comment: @Sharon, да. Я правил вторую грамматическую основу в своём ответе; мне кажется, "что за" означает "какой". Двоеточие не неграмотно здесь.

Comment: Посмотрите внимательно мой ответ. Я считаю, что основа:  что это за человек (какой это человек). Это —  подлежащее, что за человек (какой человек) —  сказуемое. Если вы согласны, то исправьте. К примеру: "хороший человек" по грамматике считается неразложимым сочетанием и является единым членом предложения.

Comment: @Sharon, как мне найти это правило?

Comment: Это не правила, а грамматика, поэтому нужен грамматический справочник. Посмотрите эти две книги в Сети. Первая — для школьников, вторая — для студентов педвуза). 1. Литневская  http://gramota.ru/book/litnevskaya.php?part5.htm   2. Кустова Синтаксис современного русского языка  (словосочетания: стр. 6-8) https://www.rsuh.ru/upload/main/media/от%20преподавателей/sintaksis-sovremennogo-russkogo-jazyka_kustova-g_i_-i-dr_2005-256s.pdf  Их можно не читать, а просматривать нужную тему.  Здесь нужно знать основу предложения (виды сказуемых и пр.),  а  также  неразложимые сочетания (у Кустовой) .

Comment: Еще надо посмотреть в книгах тему сложноподчиненных предложений (СПП), чтобы отличать союзы (служебные слова) от союзных слов (членов предложения). В нашем случае союзное слово (какой, что за) входило в состав именного сказуемого. А Правила письма — это в основном Розенталь http://old-rozental.ru/

Comment: @Sharon, спасибо за ваши рекомендации. Теперь я понял, что сочетание "что за человек" неразложимо именно по смыслу. Я сказал про двоеточие, потому что предположил, что, читая предложение в первый раз, можно случайно увидеть союз вместо союзного слова, — и это незначительное замечание.